# Format with yapf is silently erroring

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using the Python extension, with yapf - nothing happens when I hit format:

- VSCode Version: 1.0.0
- OS Version: OSX 10.11.4

My workspace settings:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/bower_components": true,
        "**/js-build": true
    },
    "editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/joshma/.envs/venv/bin/python",
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "/Users/joshma/.envs/venv/bin/flake8",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/Users/joshma/.envs/venv/bin/yapf"
}
```

The steps I took:

1. Rewrite a function call to `foo('a'     )`
2. Verify that running `cat path/to/file.py | yapf` formats that line to be `foo('a')`
3. Select entire file, cmd + shift + p, Format Code.
4. Nothing happens :(

It's possible I don't have some path/configuration set up correctly - is there some way to debug this?

Comment: Please check the contents of the python output window. If there are any errors ,they will be displayed in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try only to **Format On Save** option:

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>
- Search for **Format On Save** option and chack it **on**.

Or add the following in **settings.json**:

```
{
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this option,

> python.formatting.formatOnSave

This is my configuration and the formatting is working,

```
"python.formatting.formatOnSave": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
"python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/bin/yapf"
```